# after update composer all vender files showing git

Tags: laravel-5, gitlab

After apdate the composer in my laravel project 5k fies showing as a changes in git. how to ignore it. i already ignore vender repository in gitignore file. please help me to sort out this.[image]

**gitignore code**

```
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
```

Comment: Maybe they were initially committed to the project and then they were ignored? You can try to `git clone` your project somewhere else and see if it comes with a vendor directory.

Comment: thanx. i have corrected the issue using "git rm -r --cached ./vender"